# module_param_array() ubuntu 11.04 (kernel 2.6.38) problem

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Hi I have problem with building `uLan` driver for `Linux`.
When I compiling it I get errors:

```
/home/tomas/hairc/ulan-build/host/ul_drv/ul_drv/ul_linux.c:73:1: error: ‘param_ops_char’ undeclared here (not in a function)
/home/tomas/hairc/ulan-build/host/ul_drv/ul_drv/ul_linux.c:73:1: error: called object ‘""’ is not a function
/home/tomas/hairc/ulan-build/host/ul_drv/ul_drv/ul_linux.c:73:1: error: expected ‘)’ before string constant
/home/tomas/hairc/ulan-build/host/ul_drv/ul_drv/ul_linux.c:73:1: error: bit-field ‘<anonymous>’ width not an integer constant
/home/tomas/hairc/ulan-build/host/ul_drv/ul_drv/ul_linux.c:73:1: error: invalid initializer
/home/tomas/hairc/ulan-build/host/ul_drv/ul_drv/ul_linux.c:73:1: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before string constant
```

This is error is same for lots of lines. there is code:

```
#if (LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(2,6,0)) 
module_param_array(chip, charp, &chip_specified, 0); //this is line 73
module_param_array(my_adr, int, &my_adr_specified, 0);
module_param_array(baud, int, &baud_specified, 0);
module_param_array(irq, int, &irq_specified, 0);
module_param_array(port, int, &port_specified, 0);
module_param_array(baudbase, int, &baudbase_specified, 0);
#if defined(UL_WITH_PCI) || defined(UL_WITH_USB)
module_param_array(slot, charp, &slot_specified, 0);
#endif
module_param(debug, int, 0);
module_param(ul_usb_msg_inpr, int, 0);
module_param(ulbuffer, int, 0);
```

At old version of kernel it runs ok (now I have 2.6.38). 
Does anybody know where is a problem? 
It will helps me a lot.
Thanks

Comment: How are you attempting to compile the uLan driver? Do you have all the build dependencies installed for compiling kernel modules? (Including the proper kernel headers?)

Answer (score 1):

The actual updated version from GIT repository has been successfully tested with 2.6.38. Some update is still required for build with 2.6.39 up and 3.0 Linux kernel version.

By the way, why you do not use standard channels to communicate ( http://sourceforge.net/projects/ulan/ Forums and e/mails) with project developers?